# using lm function in R with a variable name in a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple linear model in R a for loop where one of the variables will be specified as a parameter and thus looped through, creating a different model for each pass of the loop.  The following does NOT work:

```
   model <- lm(test_par[i] ~ weeks, data=all_data_plant)
```

If I tried the same model with the "test_par[i]" replaced with the variable's explicit name, it works just as expected:

```
   model <- lm(weight_dry ~ weeks, data=all_data_plant)
```

I tried reformulate and paste ineffectively. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the argument "formula" in `lm()` as character using `paste()`. Here a working example:

```r
data("trees")
test_par <- names(trees)

model <- lm(Girth ~ Height, data = trees)
model <- lm("Girth ~ Height", data = trees)  # character formula works
model <- lm(paste(test_par[1], "~ Height"), data=trees)
```

Comment: excellent, that worked!!

Comment: Great! You can then mark this answer as "accepted".

Comment: A follow up question - how would I generate a ggplot of this. The following didn't work:
dw_trend3 <- ggplot(data=all_data_plant,aes(x=weeks, y=test_par[j]))+
  geom_point()
  print(dw_trend3)

Comment: Or should I post that as a separate question and mark this one accepted?

Comment: I think you should post another question. And more importantly, you should precise how it did not work (e.g., display the error message, show a plot output) and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE). It will greatly help your helpers...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
n <-   #add the column position of first variable
m <-   #add the column position of last variable

lm_models <- lapply(n:m, function(x) lm(all_data_plant[,x] ~ weeks, data=all_data_plant))
```

Comment: This is actually in a nested loop where I am varying other parameters as well and passing the coefficients to a dataframe for plotting at the end. So, maybe I need to think through your response more but I am not yet seeing if I can do what you suggested in this nested loop and get the results I am trying to achieve.